# Should I move sounds and images with a powerpoint file?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation which includes sounds and images.

Do I need to move the other files connected to it, such as the images and sounds, when I move the file to another machine?

Answer (score 1):

No. Images, videos and sounds used in the presentation will be bundled into the file. This will of course increase the file size.

On a side note, it's worth noting that by default fonts are *not* included. If you are using standard out-of-the-box fonts this won't be a problem, but if you're using something unusual to be opened on a different computer, you will need to embed the font. On the Save As dialogue, click the Tools button and choose Save Options. You can ask PowerPoint to include the fonts along with the presentation, also with an increased file size.

Comment: Not so.  It depends on the version of PowerPoint and how you've inserted the media.  In PPT 2010, sounds, videos and pictures will be embedded by default, not linked, but the user is free to link them if desired.  If linked, the files must stay with the presentation.  In earlier versions of PPT, videos are ALWAYS linked, never embedded; WAV sounds are embedded by default; other sounds are always linked.  Re fonts:  good advice, but note that only TrueType fonts, and not all of those, can be embedded.

Comment: Good call @SteveRindsberg, I had 2007-2010 in mind when writing this answer.

Comment: I guess an easy way to check would be to move the sounds etc. to a different location temporarily. If they're linked and not embedded, the PPT will break.

Comment: @Karan that's one way of doing it; could also use my FixLinks add-in. It's a commercial/for-sale add-in but the free demo includes a link reporting tool that'll list each link in the presentation, what file the link points to, what slide it's on and whether the link's still good or not.  Saves all that file-fiddling.  http://www.pptools.com/fixlinks/  The free demo can also convert linked images to embedded.